# UpdateProgress not working on initial page load

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

What do I need to do to make my UpdateProgress in my updatePanel to show on the initial page load? It works fine after you sort the grid that I have in my updatepanel, etc on the same page but not on the intial page load. What can I do? Here is a sample of my code. I do not have any code for this in my codebehind so that might be some of the problem im not sure.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress"
AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"
runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="postback-loader">
         <img src="Images/ajax-loader-blue.gif" style="margin:11px auto;display:block;" /><br />
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Loading Computers..." Width="170px"></asp:Label>
        </div>                   
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: Is all your data bound during the page load? If so, your update progress would never show because it is getting all the data before it shows your page and your update progress.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return control back to the page and then perform a partial postback to update the contents of your UpdatePanel using jQuery to initialise the postback.

Here's a quick example I've knocked together:

**Markup**

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            __doPostBack('<%=UpdatePanel1.ClientID %>');
        });
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div id="postback-loader">
                <img src="Images/ajax-loader-blue.gif" style="margin: 11px auto; display: block;" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Loading Computers..." Width="170px"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</form>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        TextBox1.Text = "First Load";
}

protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        TextBox1.Text = "Finished";
    }
}
```